# Audio working on linux but not working on WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, speakers

I'm using a USB powered speaker on my desktop computer running on an **ASUS PG5C MX/1333** motherboard. Initially I was using Windows XP during which time the speaker was working fine. Recently I upgraded to **Windows 7 32 bit**, and from then on I'm not able to get the speaker to work. First I tried with the default audio drivers that come with windows 7 and it did not work. Then I downloaded and installed the audio drivers recommended by ASUS for my motherboard from their site - **Realtek High Definition Audio 6.0.1.5904**. But still the speakers were dead. To confirm whether the issue was with my hardware itself, I booted with Ubuntu(using the try ubuntu option without actually installing it on my system) and played a youtube video. There I was able to get the audio without any issues.

Comment: in your tray you should find "Realtek HD Audio Manager". what devices are shown under "Audio Devices"?

Comment: There are 2 devices shown. 1 - Speakers which has a description saying Not Plugged In. 2 - Realtek Digital Output that says Default Device.

Comment: when you play somthing, does the signal graphic light up to indicate signal to one of the channels?

Comment: Yes. If I open the windows volume control, I can see the green bar indicating the signal level

Comment: it sounds like your software is correctly configured. do the tests play sounds? aside from channel muting, I don't know what else to tell you. the speakers are plugged into the light green port out of your sound card, right?

Comment: Yeah.. everything seems fine to me too but no sound :(. The test sounds are also not playing. And yes the hardware is plugged into the right port.